# How to configure Microsoft SQL Server connection while using github codespaces

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, codespaces

I am running an ASP.NET web app on my codespaces, I am trying to connect to local instance of SQL Server, I am getting the error shown here.

I have enabled filewall for remote connection to the port where SQL Server is running.

This is the error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
>
> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known at

Comment: The error _Name or service not known_ suggests problems connecting to the SQL Server Browser service. Do you have an instance name in your connection string? Have you opened up udp/1434 access in your firewall? Instance name resolution isn't likely to work through a NAT-based firewall because your public internet address won't match the address(es) returned in the SSRP responses from the SQL Server Browser service.

Comment: yes i have an instance name , also I have allowed connection via specified sql server port

Comment: Remove the instance name and use the correct port. e.g.: if your connection string includes `Server=tcp:1.2.3.4\MY_INSTANCE;` then the client first queries the SQL Browser service via 1.2.3.4 on udp/1434 to ask it "What address and port is `MY_INSTANCE` listening on", then the connects to that address and port to execute SQL queries. The problem is that SQL Browser doesn't know about your NAT-based firewall's public IP address, 1.2.3.4, so its SSRP response says, "connect to 192.168.0.10 on port 5678" which your client can't connect to. Use `Server=tcp:1.2.3.4,5678;` (with your port) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect GitHub Codespaces to resources on a private network, including package registries, license servers, and on-premises databases.

https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/developing-in-codespaces/connecting-to-a-private-network